# I'm creating a To do list and there is a problem that I can't solve

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm a beginner and Just started learning Javascript, but this is the problem that I can't solve, and here is my code:

```
add = document.getElementById("add");
add.addEventListener("click", () => {
console.log("Please wait a while...Updating List...")
tit = document.getElementById('title').value;
des = document.getElementById('descreption').value;
if (localStorage.getItem('name') == null) {
    itemJsonArray = []
    itemJsonArray.push([tit, des])
    localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray))
}

else {
    itemJsonArrayStr = localStorage.getItem('name')
    itemJsonArray = JSON.parse(itemJsonArrayStr)
    itemJsonArray.push([tit, des]);
    localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArrayStr))
}
```

When I do localStorage.getItem('name')
It always shows the following ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: itemJsonArray.push is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.

});

And here is my HTML code:

```
   <div class="nav">
    <div class="float_nav">
        <li class="mt" type="none"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="mt" type="none"><a target="_blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Project%201%20(Javascript)/Project1(Clock).HTML">Current Time</a></li>
        <li class="mt" type="none"><a target="_blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Javscript%20Course/Script.HTML">Our Course</a></li>
        <li class="mt" type="none"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKB-YGF14SY&t=12243s">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="purple" type="none"><button class="button button-to">
                <a class="black" target="_blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Project%201
    %20(Javascript)/Project1(Clock).HTML">
                    Find Your List</a></button></li>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="form">
    <div>
        <h1 class="space">Todo List</h1>
        <label class="space">Title</label><br>
        <input id="title" class="space" required type="text" placeholder="Title"><br>
        <p>Write your title</p>
        <label id="margin-top">Descreption<br>
            <textarea id="descreption" name="textarea" id="text" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>

            <div class="check">
                <!-- <label class="space" for="check">check</label> -->
                <button type="submit" id="add" class="button-2 button-to">Add To List</button>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="tb">

    <div class="td">

        <div class="tc">
            <p>No.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Descreption</p>
        </div>

        <div class="br" class="tc">
            <p>Actions</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tr">

        <div class="tc">
            <p>1.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Descreption</p>
        </div>

        <div class="br" class="tc">
            <button class="button-to">Delete</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tr">

        <div class="tc">
            <p>1.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Descreption</p>
        </div>

        <div class="br" class="tc">
            <button class="button-to">Delete</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tr">

        <div class="tc">
            <p>1.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Descreption</p>
        </div>

        <div class="br" class="tc">
            <button class="button-to">Delete</button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tr">

        <div class="tc">
            <p>1.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>

        <div class="tc">
            <p>Descreption</p>
        </div>

        <div class="br" class="tc">
            <button class="button-to">Delete</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<script src="Java.js"></script>
```

First I thought that It should work, But it did't...

Comment: Did you try to check what `itemJsonArray`  contains in case that error is thrown?

Comment: Also, please don't use irrelevant tags - or explain how your problem is related to CSS

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be that you are not initializing new variables properly. Create them using `var`, `let` or `const` (explaining the difference: [link](https://youtu.be/9WIJQDvt4Us)). Your code does work because you are not in strict mode.

If I am mistaken and you do initialize them properly, than add the variable initialization part in your snippets. As Nico Haase suggests, try to `console.log` your `itemJsonArray` to see what it is exactly

Comment: If you are not sure what the problem is, ask for clarification in an answer. Don't post answers that do not resolve the problem. Also, if there was a problem with initializing the variable itself, shouldn't the error look different?